Brightness not setting back to previous setting
Ubuntu 24.04 with Gnome 46
Automatic brightness is turned off.
I set the brightness every time to minimum for the laptop screen.
Every time I boot up, the brightness is at 5% setting, I have to change it back to minimum manually.
How can I fix this?
systemd[]: Starting systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service - Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight...
systemd-backlight[]: intel_backlight: Saved brightness 960 is too low; increasing to 4800.

later
systemd[]: Finished systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service - Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight.

Every time I run a systemctl stop systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight it changes the brightness back up to the 5%, if it was below it.
SYSTEMD-BACKLIGHT@.SERVICE(8)                                                                               systemd-backlight@.service                                                                              SYSTEMD-BACKLIGHT@.SERVICE(8)

NAME
       systemd-backlight@.service, systemd-backlight - Load and save the display backlight brightness at boot and shutdown

SYNOPSIS
       systemd-backlight@.service

       /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-backlight save [backlight|leds]:DEVICE

       /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-backlight load [backlight|leds]:DEVICE

DESCRIPTION
       systemd-backlight@.service is a service that restores the display backlight brightness at early boot and saves it at shutdown. On disk, the backlight brightness is stored in /var/lib/systemd/backlight/. During loading, if the udev
       property ID_BACKLIGHT_CLAMP is not set to false, the brightness is clamped to a value of at least 1 or 5% of maximum brightness, whichever is greater. The percentage can be adjusted by specifying a percentage (needs to be suffixed
       with "%", e.g.  "30%") to the property ID_BACKLIGHT_CLAMP.

KERNEL COMMAND LINE
       systemd-backlight understands the following kernel command line parameter:

       systemd.restore_state=
           Takes a boolean argument. Defaults to "1". If "0", does not restore the backlight settings on boot. However, settings will still be stored on shutdown.

           Added in version 209.

SEE ALSO
       systemd(1)

Related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184949
Related: Fixing brightness levels in 15.04 with systemd
Workaround
With
sudo nano /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
change
SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", TAG+="systemd", IMPORT{builtin}="path_id", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="systemd-backlight@backlight:$name.service"

to
SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", TAG+="systemd", IMPORT{builtin}="path_id", ENV{ID_BACKLIGHT_CLAMP}=="false", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="systemd-backlight@backlight:$name.service"

or similar, adding the ENV{ID_BACKLIGHT_CLAMP}="0".
This fixed the issue on my system, and subsequent executions of the command sudo systemctl restart systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight do not raise the brightness back up to the 5% minimum!
How can I make this default behavior? Is the default of preventing going below the 1-5% threshold to prevent daft backlights from being blank on startup? But the user would have had to been using the monitor at that brightness level when turning the computer off, or last updating the brightness value. Anyway, on first boot the monitor brightness is set high. I don't see if this prevention is still necessary.
